# Show only marker in SSRS report or show line for one column only in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I need to show three columns in a chart in SSRS, however one of the columns should only show as either a marker or a line. I am attaching an example of what I need to do.

[image]

Comment: Really Kev, of course I have researched the issue. This is a requirement that I have to. This is not a trend line as trend lines cannot be broken apart. I see you cannot show a marker without showing the column so thanks for not helping.

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by adding 3rd data column as "Range column", this is done by changing its chart type.

Firstly I created a new report, added a bar chart to it using the following query to give me some data to play with:

```
select 'blue' as 'group', 80 as value1, 60 as value2, 25 as value3
union all select 'red' as 'group', 50 as value1, 75 as value2, 40 as value3
```

Added "value1" and "value3" as data values to the chart, and the "group" column as category.

**The Important Bit:**

Next added "value2" as third data value, then changed its chart type to be a Range Column, found under the [Range of chart types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207148.aspx).

Then update the Series Properties adding the Bottom value as:

```
=Sum(Fields!value2.Value)-3
```

**Final Solution Preview:**

[image: **Final solution preview**]

Comment: I have the same need.  Your solution is working really well for me, but what is the "-3" on your Bottom value: "=Sum(Fields!value2.Value)-3" ?  Just trying to understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: In order for the range column to display as line we need to set a bottom value and top value, what its doing is saying the range column goes from `x` to `x-3` (using sample data: 60-57, 75-72) so it displays as block. You could change the value to fit your formatting needs.

Comment: Ah, I get it.  So the x-3 determines the thickness of the line.  Excellent solution, many thanks!